# Applying normal map increases shadow contrast

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

Applying a normal map to my mesh makes the render use almost only 2 shades of grey and creates very contrasting shadows
Here is a render with normal map:
[image]
And here is one without:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to set the *Image Texture* node to **Non-color Data** type, and secondly you need to run it through *Normal Map* node as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Your answer helped, but I immediatly ran into another problem, the shades seem diiferent on pathces of the render, i have added a screenshot too my question.

Comment: When you click on the field, where it currently states `UV Map`, in the *Normal Map* node, do any other options instead of `UV Map` show?

Comment: No Uv map is the only option, I think it could be something to do with flipped uv's, since the patches correspond with the uv islands, but I'm not sure.

Comment: One thing, where is the normal map from (did you baked it or did it come with the model) and why do you need it, because the model without it looks pretty detailed?

Comment: I baked it, I want to add a little more detail, since the original mesh I sculpted gets too laggy when texturing, so I copied the mesh, lowered the subdivisions by one and baked the normal map onto it.

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest you to try a different normal map (downloaded from net) instead of the baked, and you will see if the patches persists. If they disappear then the current normal map was incorrectly baked.