# Very annoying lines on the normal map

Tags: baking

[image]

This is a little detailed sculpture on my character's cloth.
Then I unwrap UP and bake the normal map.

[image]

However, there is always an annoying cut line show up on the unwrap lines.

[image]

This only shows on the cloth.
This is the normal map.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your low-poly and high-poly objects? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I use multiresolution to sculpture, then use bake from multires.

Comment: so could you share the object?

Comment: How does the Shader nodes look like? Have you set the Color Space of the Image Texture node to Non-Color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying normal map increases shadow contrast](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66515/applying-normal-map-increases-shadow-contrast)

Comment: Looks like the low poly model has some inverted normals. Try to recalculate normals ("recalculate outside")

Comment: Yes! I  should change the image Texture from "RGB" to "Linear". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by how it looks and where it lines up, I'm fairly certain your normal map texture is not properly set as Non-Color. This must be set **before** you bake to it.

Comment: yes, this was the cause. See the last hidden comment above.

Comment: oh my bad, with so many bad takes going back I hadn't noticed your comment and OP's follow up. Perhaps OP should mark the question solved or edit the prompt

Answer (score 1):

Those dark lines indicate inconsistant **normals**.
[image]

You can find them easily with **Overlay > Face Orientation**: blue is forward, red is backward.
[image]

To fix those you can either select all polygons and *recalculate normals* or flip a selected area of normals manually with the *flip normals* command.

Comment: The normal is right.